# Flutter Video Player On Click Pass URL dynamic and Load Video to play

Tags: flutter, video-player

[sample screen of video player attached below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoeyX.png) How can i make video player to play dynamically , while onclick of list play video by passing the video URL?

while on click i have passed URL and tried to reinitialise and start play its not working ,state not changing

Here is my code,

videoplayerscreen.dart,

```
class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  int playBackTime;
  int playBackTotalTime;
  String setPlayTime;
  String setPlayDuration;
  double aspectRatio;
  String videoUrl;
  bool isForward;
  bool isFullScreen;
  bool allowFullScreen;
  bool showControls;
  bool isAutoPlay;
  int startWithinSeconds;

  VideoPlayerScreen({
    Key key,
    this.playBackTime = 0,
    this.playBackTotalTime = 0,
    this.setPlayTime = "00:00",
    this.setPlayDuration = "00:00",
    this.aspectRatio = 16 / 9,
    this.videoUrl =
        "",
    this.isForward = true,
    this.isFullScreen = false,
    this.allowFullScreen = false,
    this.showControls = true,
    this.isAutoPlay = false,
    this.startWithinSeconds = 0,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  void initPlayer() async {
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.videoUrl);
    await _controller.initialize();
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.seekTo(Duration(seconds: widget.startWithinSeconds));
    if (widget.isAutoPlay) {
      _controller.play();
    }
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        widget.playBackTime = _controller.value.position.inSeconds;
        widget.setPlayTime = timeFormatter(widget.playBackTime);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initPlayer();
    super.initState();
  }

 @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

In Config,

`video_player: ^0.10.5`

Calling in Other class CourseDetails.dart ,

```
             Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    child: _playUrl != null
                        ? VideoPlayerScreen(videoUrl: _playUrl)
                        : Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/test_video_player_screen.png'),
                  ),
                )
```

```
GestureDetector(
 **here i am changing the state **
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
            _playUrl = videoLists['course_video_url'];
        });
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 20.0, top: 2.0, bottom: 5.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "${videoLists['sn_no']}",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black45,
                  fontFamily: 'Oswald-SemiBold'),
            ),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "${videoLists['course_video_title']}",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.black45,
                        fontFamily: 'Oswald-SemiBold'),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Video - ${videoLists['course_video_duration']}",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontFamily: 'Oswald-SemiBold'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                        child: videoLists['course_watched']
                            ? Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/green_tick_icon.png',
                                width: 12.0,
                                height: 12.0,
                              )
                            : null),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you are doing with this Class initialisation inside a `setState` on your `onTap`? There are few confusing things in this piece of code that make it difficult for us to help you debug.

Comment: ya sure i will explain,
Actually i have created two classes,

1.VideoPlayerScreen
2.CourseDetails


In CourseDetails.dart ,

I am calling the rest api to get the Lists of VideoURL and showing in the listview,
That **onTap** is called when user clicks the particular list item.

On that time im passing the URL to **VideoPlayerScreen.dart** to play the video ,
hence on first time it is playing, on next click video url is passing but video not playing,

help me to fix it how to make dynamicaly play video player on passing URL @JoãoSoares

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all the replies. I got the solution:

In `Build` Function, I have checked if any url changes happened or not. If changes happened, I disposed old controller and I reinitialized video controller. Then, it works fine for me.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (currentObjectVideoUrl != widget.videoUrl) {
       _controller.dispose();
       initPlayer();
    }
}
```

Comment: How to find currentObjectVideoUrl ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a stateful widget passing a URL. Then inside the init method, you can do this

```
class ViewVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  final link;
  ViewVideo(this.link);
  @override
  _ViewVideoState createState() => _ViewVideoState(this.link);
}

class _ViewVideoState extends State<ViewVideo> {
  final link;
  _ViewVideoState(this.link);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Write your video player code here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
     //Here you can close the video player
     super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: i have tried same thing but still not working , it is not destroying old video and not playing new video @K K

Comment: i have modified the questions and added my code briefly @ K K

Comment: you have to add the dispose method and close the existing controller. Check the code I have updated.

Comment: yes i have added already 
` @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }`

Comment: @KK, I have also tried your method. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified my response based on your comments. You just need to have your video url on a class variable that you change with the setState. Then on your Widgets have a check for the presence of the variable and decide to show the `VideoPlayerScreen` widget or an empty box.

```
String videoUrl = '';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      videoUrl == '' ? SizedBox() : VideoPlayerScreen(videoUrl: videoUrl),
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState((){
            videoUrl == videoLists['course_video_url'];
          });
        }
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: hi, but i am doing in one screen , here i am attaching the image of design , (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoeyX.png)
In  this image list of URL are there on click i m playing the video on the top
 @João Soares

Comment: @Jai I've modified my response to fit what you commented.

Comment: @Jao Soares same thing i have done but still not working , please check my question i have added code briefly what i have done

Comment: @Jai Where is the build method in your VideoPlayerScreen class that is displaying the video, can you share that?

Comment: VideoPlayerScreen  build method,

`
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 if (_controller.value.initialized) {
  AspectRatio(
         aspectRatio: widget.aspectRatio,
         child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
     )
 }
}
`
@Joao Soares

Comment: @Jai I feel like there are other problems in your code that we can't fully see here. The theory should be correct, but based on of the code you showed us, some things are very wrong. And it would likely take a full look at the everything involved to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `didUpdateWidget` method.

We can compare any property of the Widget class and according to that reset the player.

For resetting, general steps would be

1. stop the player
2. close the session
3. initialize player again (with new URL and other parameters)

Below is the code snippet for logic.

```dart
class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  void initPlayer() async {
    /// initialise player
  }

  void disposePlayer() {
    /// dispose player
  }

  void resetPlayer() {
    disposePlayer();
    initPlayer();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initPlayer();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(VideoPlayerScreen oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (oldWidget.videoUrl != widget.videoUrl) {
      resetPlayer();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    disposePlayer();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Reference for [didUpdateWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) method.

Answer (score 0):

@Jai Techie I think you have already found the solution, But I will add some more explanation to it for those who still have got some errors using the video_player package.

Actually, when we are loading another video from the list of videos using network URLs, we create another instance of our videoController and initialize it without destroying the previous one.

Another big issue is that **The video_player plugin fails to play videos after playing successfully 10-15 times** stated here on GitHub video_player [issue/24565](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24565).

First of all, we will use a [Chewie Wrapper Package](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) which is a wrapper package around the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package.

```
 /// initialize the videoController
  void _initController(String link) {
   _videoController = VideoPlayerController.network(link)
    ..initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {});
    //do what you want.
      _videoController?.play();
  });
chewieController = ChewieController(
    videoPlayerController: _videoController!,
);
}

 Future<void> _startVideoPlayer(String link) async {
  if (_videoController == null && chewieController == null) {
    // If there was no controller, just create a new one
    _initController(link);

    } else {
     // If there was a controller, we need to dispose of the old one first
    final oldController = _videoController;
    final oldChewieController = chewieController;

    // Registering a callback for the end of the next frame
    // to dispose of an old controller
    // (which won't be used anymore after calling setState)

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    await oldController?.dispose();
    oldChewieController?.dispose();

    // Initing new controller
    _initController(link);
  });

  //Make sure that the controller is not used by setting it to null

  setState(() {
    _videoController = null;
  });

}
}
```

*Now call this method from your initState*

```
_startVideoPlayer('your URL here')
```

*And also call it from your listview (list of videos) onTap property*

```
_startVideoPlayer(listOfVideos[index].URLS.toString())
```

Just Create a method *_startVideoPlayer()* where it will check if videoController is initialized or not. If videoController is not initialized it will call the *initController()*, if it is already initialized, first we have to *dispose()* of that videoController after disposing of it then initialize the new one.

I hope it will work.